# Passing Id to bootstrap modal popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-modal

Here is working after tweak to JQuery:

```
$(.modalLink").click(function () {
     var passedID = $(this).data('id');
     $('#id').val(passedID);
     $(".modal-body .hiddenid").val(passedID);
});
```

//View Link

```
<a href="/Home/Employee/id=@item.Id" data-id="@item.Id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Load me</a>
```

How to capture the Id that I'm passing when the `<a href` click?

So I have a modal popup and when the user clicks I want to get the id of it when the user post the data.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Employee", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Record</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="FirstName" class="control-label">First Name:</label>
                        @Html.Editor("FirstName", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="LastName" class="control-label">Last Name:</label>
                        @Html.Editor("LastName", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Employee(string id, string FirstName, string LastName)
{
     //more work here..
     return View("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need a class or something you can use to reference the links:

```
<a href="/Home/Employee/id=@item.Id" data-id="@item.Id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="modalLink">Load me</a>
```

You need a hidden form field to hold the id that will be submitted with the form. So put this in your modal form:

```
@Html.Hidden("id", "", new { @class = "hiddenid" })
```

Then, just use some javascript. I assume jQuery would work fine for you?

```
$(document).on("click", ".modalLink", function () {
     var passedID = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body .hiddenid").val(passedID);
});
```

Comment: 1+ Thanks, how would I get that `Id` in the controller?

Comment: The model binder matches them by name when the form is posted. That first param of the Html.Hidden helper aka the input name has to match the param name on your controller. Also... if your Id is numeric, you may consider changing it to `public ActionResult Employee(int id, string FirstName, string LastName)` to use int instead of string.